# Как Qt научить понимать пробелы в путях к файлу?

Tags: c++, файлы, qt

Вот немного моего кода:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonSave_clicked()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Save Document"),
                                                    QDir::currentPath(),
                                                    tr("Document files (*.doc *.rtf);;All files (*.*)") );

    //QMessageBox q;
    //q.setText(filename);
    //q.exec();

    string path = filename.toUtf8().constData();
    QString s = ui->order->toPlainText();
    s += "_______\n";
    s += ui->lineEditAll->text();
    string text = s.toStdString();

    ofstream fout(path.c_str());
    fout << text.c_str();
    fout.close();

}
```

Но сохраняет мой файл только в те директории, где нет пробелов в пути.

Comment: попробуй экранировать пробелы с помощью "\".
Document\ files

Comment: Попробуйте QDir::fromNativeSeparators так:

    void MainWindow::on_pushButtonSave_clicked()
    {
        QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Save Document"),
                                                    QDir::currentPath(),
                                                    tr("Document files (*.doc *.rtf);;All files (*.*)") );

    QString path = QDir::fromNativeSeparators(filename);
    ...
    }

Answer (score 1):

Надо было найденные слеши ("/") заменить на ("\\")

Comment: А просто 
QString path = QDir::fromNativeSeparators(filename);
не работает?

Comment: @abalckin пробовал не прокатило

Answer (score 1):

На всех платформах в Qt используются только пути с прямым слешом (`/`). Лучше всего для записи в файл тоже использовать Qt (`QFile`). Если же требуется использовать нативные средства для операций с файлом, то перед передачей в пути к файлу нужно заменить слеши на те, которые используются в данной ОС:

```
string path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(filename).toStdString();
```